# Which statement is more correct, "is getting updated" or "is being updated"?

Tags: grammaticality, passive-voice

> The parameters is getting updated when you change the project rate.
>
> The parameters is being updated when you change the project rate.

Is there a difference between these two statements? Which statement is more correct from a grammatical point of view?

Comment: First of all, parameters with an s **are**. I advise newbies against using get meaning to become unless you mean get rich, get sick, etc.

Comment: Unless the update is a process, I would use neither and opt for "The parameters are updated when the project rate is changed." Your versions could give the impression that a team of workers are pulling levers behind the scenes. The "you" (for user) is often  implicit in more formal instructions/descriptions, but it's not wrong to include it.  (I assume your readers know what the *project rate* is.)

Comment: This really needs more details to be a good SE question. What is the relationship between the two things: does one cause the other, are they simultaneous, are they unrelated?